# Reverted with reason string 'Governor: unknown proposal id

Tags: openzeppelin-contracts, dao

I using Governor contract from Openzeppelin. I have create the proposal and voted on the proposal. The state of proposal is succeeded. When I am trying to queue the proposal I am getting error

> Reverted with reason string 'Governor: unknown proposal id

This is the proposal transaction:
[image: Proposal Transaction]

These are the details have entered for queue:
[image: Queue Transaction details]

My contract is deployed on [sepolia](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x1f8AEc0A9623d807706DF21341b2ca2594a17F3B)